# Getting particular word from file having particular special prefix character

Tags: text-processing

I have a file from which I need all particular words having @ prefix. The file looks something like this

```
@abc fffg, @bcdg pnkout , @ghj sms , @yth txt= 5 ,@dfg call.
```

The file has many more lines similarly.
The output needs to be like this

```
@abc
@bcdg 
@ghj
@yth
@dfg
...
```

all in new line.

Comment: The file has many more lines .. similarly . The output needs to be

Comment: So your file is one line long?  You say “I need particular word having `@`”.  There are five words containing `@` in your sample data; which one do you want?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Have edited my question . I need only those words which are having @prefixed to the word

Comment: So why not `@yth`?

Comment: yes it is also required .. all words  having @

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Po '(^|\W)\K@\w+' inputfile
@abc
@bcdg
@ghj
@yth
@dfg
```

Comment: This question is terribly unclear, but the OP said “I need only those words which are having @prefixed to the word” and excluded `@dfg`, so, maybe, they want only “words” (strings of non-blank characters) that begin with `@`. So maybe, instead of `\W` and `\w`, you should be using ``\s`` and ``\S``.

Answer (score 0):

awk solution. Strips characters before '@' symbols as `,@dfg` in input becomes `@dfg`, and if this is needed for the end to strip punctuation then would be easy to sort:

```
 ~$> echo '@abc fffg, @bcdg pnkout , @ghj sms , @yth txt= 5 ,@dfg call.' |
> awk 'BEGIN { RS="[[:space:]]+" } /^[^[:alnum:]]*@.*/ { sub("^[^@]*", ""); print }'
@abc
@bcdg
@ghj
@yth
@dfg
```

And easier to read...

```
# split records on, and clear all spaces etc.
BEGIN { RS="[[:space:]]+" } 

# matching any record that has an '@' in, without letters before it
/^[^[:alpha:]]*@.*/ { 
    # strip before '@'
    sub("^[^@]*", "")
    # remove non-letters at end if needed
    # sub("[^[:alpha:]]*$", "")
    print 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below combination of sed awk oneliner is used to achieve the same. Tested it worked fine. Let me know for any doubts

command

```
echo "@abc fffg, @bcdg pnkout , @ghj sms , @yth txt= 5 ,@dfg call." | sed "s/,/\n/g"| awk '{print $1}'
```

output

```
@abc
@bcdg
@ghj
@yth
@dfg
```